# Parsing issues in Antlr3 for Linux and Windows

Tags: linux, antlr3

I am trying to parse a piece of trigger code using antlr. While I was able to parse it successfully on Windows, it results in an exception in Linux for the function `MATCHT()` (which is in turn calling the `match()` function).

What is the difference for this between Linux and Windows?

Comment: Have you properly handled new lines? Windows uses \r\n while Linux uses \n

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a problem of the ANTLR3 runtime (you are using the C target?). On Linux the runtime could be installed in the system lib path and hence might be outdated. On Windows the runtime must be part of the application, so it could be it uses a newer version. I have seen several bugs in the runtime and even at the time being [not all of them are fixed](https://github.com/antlr/antlr3/pulls).

Comment: But this issue is in the grammar files that are generated from antlr-.3.4-complete jar

Comment: Doesn't matter. The generated parser needs a runtime in the target language and this runtime might have bugs/errors. The runtime contains support classes/code for the parser to make it actually work.